# different ssl_protocols for separate domains

Tags: ssl, nginx

I tried to configure one server for a specific domain to use TLSv2.0 only. Others should use TLSv1, TLSv1.1, and TLSv2.0.

The configuration is valid, as nginx loads correctly, but the site with TLSv2.0 only is also accessible via the other protocols.

Is it possible to use this configuration or are the SSL protocols restricted to all servers?

The configuration should look like this:

```
server {
    server_name foo.bar.com;
    [...]
    ssl_protocols TLSv2.0;
}
server {
    server_name baz.bar.com;
    [...]
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv2.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ssl_protocols`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_protocols) can be defined at `server` level, so it means it may be applied differently for every server, so the problem does not come from that.

1. Ensure you configuration is applied correctly (error log neither after `nginx -t` is issued or after nginx reload)
2. Ensure you specify the right server name during you SSL test and that your request is served by this specific server block (and not another one, acting as default server for example)

How have you tested your servers? Could you provide commands and their output?